# WordPress Custom Post Type with editable / flexible slug (permalink structure)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I'm currently looking for the best solution to create a custom post type in wordpress with an user editable slug. The custom post type is registered in a plugin, for example this one:

```
$labels = array(
    'name'               => _x( 'Team', 'post type general name', 'text-domain' ),
    'singular_name'      => _x( 'Team Member', 'post type singular name', 'text-domain' ),
    'menu_name'          => _x( 'Team', 'admin menu', 'text-domain' ),
    'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Team', 'add new on admin bar', 'text-domain' ),
    'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'Property', 'text-domain' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Team Member', 'text-domain' ),
    'new_item'           => __( 'New Team Member', 'text-domain' ),
    'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Team Member', 'text-domain' ),
    'view_item'          => __( 'View Team Member', 'text-domain' ),
    'all_items'          => __( 'All Team Members', 'text-domain' ),
    'search_items'       => __( 'Search Team Member', 'text-domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Team Member:', 'text-domain' ),
    'not_found'          => __( 'No team members found.', 'text-domain' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No team members found in Trash.', 'text-domain' )
);

$args = array(
    'labels'             => $labels,
    'description'        => __( 'Custom Post Type for your Team Members.', 'text-domain' ),
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'team' ),
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'menu_position'      => null,
    'supports'           => array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'author',
        'thumbnail',
        'excerpt'
    )
);
```

In this example the slugs name is "team" and it's hard-coded. What is the best solution to give the plugin user the possibility to change this slug to a custom one. Maybe a similar solution like WooCommerce provides with the settings for product category base under "settings > permalinks".

Comment: I don't know if slug can be different than custom post's type..

Comment: Hi Antonis, yes generally its possible to set a different name and slug for a custom post type, but I think for a plugin it's not really cool to force a slug for the user.

Comment: Have you tried passing to that slug a custom field which is inserted by user? Just remember , custom post types are called through `init` . Try to read that custom field on `after_setup_theme` which is called before `init`

Comment: Yes, I think it could be possible over one of these action hooks. But I thought about a solution based on WordPress rewrite and permalink functions, this could be a more elegant way to do that. But I'm not sure what's the best point to start there.